# Getting pyodbc to connect in AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc, aws-lambda-layers

I have built deployment package to connect to a AWS RDS instance via pyodbc, after zipping up and uploading to AWS lambda this connection works.

When trying to connect via an AWS layer, following error is displayed.

```
"errorMessage": "('01000', \"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)\")",
  "errorType": "Error",
```

Tried to change the path for the driver in the odbcinst.ini file, but with no luck

Example of text in odbcinst.ini file

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/var/task/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@narayan.anurag/breaking-the-ice-between-aws-lambda-pyodbc-6f53d5e2bd26 might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use ODBC Driver *17* then I recommend Alexander's pyodbc layer which you can find on GitHub: https://github.com/alexanderluiscampino/lambda-layers

There's also a discussion of it when it was first being constructed that can be helpful for context: https://gist.github.com/diriver63/b72a954fa0da4851d89e5086aa13c6e8

I've used this myself and had good luck with it. I originally found it after finding that pyodbc has no binary wheels and so AWS SAM can't simply install it: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1577